# how to start new activity from onpostexecute in async task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

**I have this three classes. My Mainactivity,newactivity and the one that extends the AsyncTask, Now in one that extends Asynctask I need to start new activity on OnPostExecute() in the AsyncTask. How can I do that? i have done with context but i am getting error from mainactivity executing backgroundtask line but app crashes please help **

This is mainactivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button click;
    //public static TextView data;
    public static LineChart mchart;
    List<Entry> x;
    ArrayList<String> y;
    private fetchdata list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        click=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        mchart=(LineChart)findViewById(R.id.linechart);
        //data=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fetcheddata);
        list=new fetchdata();
        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fetchdata process=new fetchdata();
                process.execute();


            }
        });


    }
}





 public class fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        String data="";
        String dataparsed="";
        String singleparsed="";
        List<Entry> x;
        List<String> y;
        boolean flag=false;


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            x = new ArrayList<Entry>();
            y = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                URL url=new URL("https://io.adafruit.com/api/v2/Yarev/feeds/pir-sensor/data");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line="";
                while (line!=null)
                {
                    line=bufferedReader.readLine();
                    data=data+line;
                }
                JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(data);
                for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject JO= (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                    singleparsed="Value:"+JO.get("value")+"\n"+
                            "Feed key:"+JO.get("feed_key")+"\n"+
                            "Created:"+JO.get("created_at")+"\n";
                    int value=JO.getInt("value");
                    float v1=value;
                    x.add(new Entry(i,v1));
                    dataparsed=dataparsed+singleparsed;
                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            //start new activity?????


        }
        public List<Entry> getList() {
            return x;
        }

    }
```

Comment: where is your activity `context`?

Comment: @pavan You need to proofread and copy edit your question it is difficult to follow, pay as close attention to your textual description as you would the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create constructor with context

```
public class fetchdata extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        String data="";
        String dataparsed="";
        String singleparsed="";
        List<Entry> x;
        List<String> y;
        boolean flag=false;

        private WeakReference<Context> contextRef;

        public fetchdata(Context context) {
            contextRef = new WeakReference<>(context);
        } 


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            x = new ArrayList<Entry>();
            y = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                URL url=new URL("https://io.adafruit.com/api/v2/Yarev/feeds/pir-sensor/data");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line="";
                while (line!=null)
                {
                    line=bufferedReader.readLine();
                    data=data+line;
                }
                JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(data);
                for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject JO= (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                    singleparsed="Value:"+JO.get("value")+"\n"+
                            "Feed key:"+JO.get("feed_key")+"\n"+
                            "Created:"+JO.get("created_at")+"\n";
                    int value=JO.getInt("value");
                    float v1=value;
                    x.add(new Entry(i,v1));
                    dataparsed=dataparsed+singleparsed;
                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

           if (context != null) {
            // start new activity with context
             Intent intent=new Intent(context,NewActivity.class);
             context.startActivity(intent);
           }


        }
        public List<Entry> getList() {
            return x;
        }

    }
```

start your tack:

```
new fetchdata(this).execute();
```

Comment: can you please elaborate how to call from mainactivity using context  and startactivity in postexecute and i have edited the problem

Comment: @pavansai i have updated answer